# tweepy error python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I keep getting this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Status is a duplicate.', u'code': 187
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error I have tried everything!

My main code is:

```
import socket
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds

url = 'http://google.co.uk'
try :
    response = urlopen( url )
except HTTPError, e:
    tweet_text = "Raspberry Pi Server is DOWN!"
    textfile = open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt','w')
    textfile.write("down")
    textfile.close()
except URLError, e:
    tweet_text = "Raspberry Pi Server is DOWN!"
    textfile = open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt','w')
    textfile.write("down")
    textfile.close()
else :
    textfile = open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt','r')
    if 'down' in open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt').read():
        tweet_text = "Raspberry Pi Server is UP!"
        textfile = open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt','w')
        textfile.write("up")
        textfile.close()
    elif 'up' in open('/root/Documents/server_check.txt').read():
        tweet_text = ""
if len(tweet_text) <= 140:
    if tweet_text == "Raspberry Pi Server is DOWN!" or tweet_text == "Raspberry Pi Server is UP!":
        api.update_status(status=tweet_text)
    else:
        pass
else:
    print "Your message is too long!"
```

I have removed the API's for security reasons! I have also removed the link to my server.
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that tweepy doesn't let you tweet the same tweet twice so to fix it i added these lines of code:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    try:
        api.destroy_status(status.id)
    except:
        pass
```

the code above deletes previous tweets so that my next tweet doesn't fail.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: be careful, this destroy all your tweets

Comment: “tweepy doesn't let you tweet the same tweet twice” this is inaccurate; Twitter does not allow duplicate Tweets. Tweepy inherits limitations from the Twitter API. It doesn’t matter which API library you use.