# Python 3.4+ PendingDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just upgraded to Python 3.4.3 and I have been getting this error while writing a piece of code:

```
PendingDeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
```

This seems like a Python version related issue.
Thanks!

Edit: This is what the entire error looks like

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py:32: PendingDeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  PendingDeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_reddit_bot_2.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "twitter_reddit_bot_2.py", line 100, in main
    tweeter(post_titles, post_links, post_ids)
  File "twitter_reddit_bot_2.py", line 124, in tweeter
    api.update_status(tweet_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 194, in update_status
    )(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Status is a duplicate.', 'code': 187}]
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.10', 50066), raddr=('104.244.42.2', 443)>
/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:2150: ImportWarning: sys.meta_path is empty
```

Comment: well the `imp` module is deprecated in favor of `importlib`; either replace all usages of `imp` with corresponding functions from `importlib` now or, be forced to do it later when it will eventually be removed

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by 'change the module using it now'.

Comment: I updated my comment to better explain myself. What is it that you are executing that is throwing this warning?

Comment: I am not directly using the imp or importlib module. I am using Twitter and Reddit APIs though for the project. The error is being pointed at `/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py:32:`.

Comment: @SaloniKogta could you edit in the **specific** modules you're using? The error location is probably just the line where the deprecation warning is thrown - isn't there a proper stack of errors?

Comment: @Aurora0001 I have updated my original question to include the entire stack trace.

Comment: @SaloniKogta I think you've missed the bigger error, which is probably similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635085/tweepy-error-python-2-7).

Comment: While this seems to work, it is also removing all the previous tweets...which destroys the purpose. But since it solves the original problem, I will accept it as an answer if you post your solution as an answer here.

Comment: @SaloniKogta sorry I didn't reply - I didn't get an inbox notification for your last message. When you're replying to someone make sure to use `@user`, which will ensure that they get a notification (you always get notifications for this post though because you're the author).

Comment: Oh alright! Didn't know that. Thanks! @Aurora0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by correcting another error, as suggested by @Aurora0001.
So from what I have understood, this error crops up when there is some other error that you are overlooking. In my case, I stopped using tweepy and used another API. This eliminated the error.